# webkit transforms CSS and overflow

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I have a div, in which its contents are being transformed using webkit css transforms. Now the div has `overflow: hidden;`, but the contents after transformation keep showing up outside the div.

Why is this?

Comment: Post a screenshot please. It seems to be a bug in the Webkit engine - you should post a bug report about it.

Comment: http://cssizer.com/ make a demo of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to say, but remember that transforms happen after the rest has been drawn. That means that the transformed element will be moved from wherever it was ignoring `overflow:hidden` as it's not overflowing, it's been transformed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Chromium after all.

`http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72309`